# how to create custom pop up box in html with two buttons and actions for each buttons

Tags: javascript, html

Any ideas on how to make the custom HTML pop up box(not pop up window) with two buttons "deactivate" and "delete". When user clicks either of the buttons respective action should be captured. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the difference between a pop-up box and pop-up window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Below links will answer your question with different example

http://codepen.io/sawyer22/pen/lAcek

http://codepen.io/stursby/pen/bpoAr

```
enter code here
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

may be this will help..
[jQuery modal popup](http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div style="display:hidden; width:333px; height:333px; background-color:red;" id="popupBox">
    <input type="button" id="deleteBtn" value="Delete"/>
    <input type="button" id="deactivateBtn" value="Deactivate"/>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#popupBox").show();

    $("#deleteBtn").click(function()
    {
        //handle button
    });

    $("#deactivateBtn").click(function()
    {
        //handle button
    });
});
```

**Or when you click on a button:**

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" id="triggerPopupBox" value="Trigger"/>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$("triggerPopupBox").click(function()
{
    $("#popupBox").show();
});
```

Comment: I want this to pop-up when I click on deactivate button. Will this do ?

Comment: The pop-up box shows when the page is done loading, in your question you said you want a pop-up box with the deactivate button included in the box. I'll include code for when you want to display the box when you click on a button.

Comment: I actually have a button "deactivate" on HTML page. When I click on that button then this pop up should appear with two buttons delete and deactivate. Depending on delete or deactivate I have to pick particular action (url).

Comment: Ok so then just replace the #triggerPopupBox button in my code with your deactivate button, what other problems are you having?